# GIFs in Python and encoding

Tags: python

I need to convert GIF to binary because I need to concatenate then the gif with a text string(which is in binary), because I am doing a Web Server in Python. The rest of the code already performs well and is able to load pictures, texts and htmls.
For gifs I have this:

```
elif format == "gif": 
     corpo = PIL.Image.open(path)
     answer =  corpo + ("\n").encode('UTF-8') #I need this line to end with a \n because it's the end of a HTTP answer
```

This gives me the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'GifImageFile' and 'bytes'", and, however, I haven't found any way to do what I am trying. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: Approximately 0.4% of the bytes in your GIF file will be newlines, just by random chance - the one you're adding at the end is utterly meaningless, because there's nothing distinguishing it from the ones that are part of the file data.

Comment: Surely you need to send a `Content-Type` of `image/gif` too? And your GIF file on disk is already binary. You surely just need to open it in binary mode and `read()` the contents - you don't need PIL to interpret it or anything.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, there is already a header saying that content-type. How would I have to  write the code to support the read() content ?

Comment: Just `import pathlib` then `corpo = pathlib.Path('image.gif').read_bytes()`

Comment: Or simply `with open('image.gif','rb') as f:` then `corpo = f.read()`

Comment: @MarkSetchell That worked! Thank you. If you want to write that as an answer I can upvote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GIF file on disk is already binary and already what a browser will expect if you send a `Content-Type: image/gif` so you just need to read its contents like this:

```
with open('image.gif', 'rb') as f:
    corpo = f.read()
```

Your variable `corpo` will then contain a GIF-encoded image, with a header with the width and height, the palette and the LZW-compressed pixels.

---

Just by way of clarification, when you use:

```
im = Image.open('image.gif')
```

PIL will create a memory buffer according to the width and height in the GIF, then uncompress all the LZW-compressed pixels into that buffer. If you then convert that to bytes, you would be sending the browser the first pixel, then the second, then the third but without any header telling it how big the image is and also you'd be sending it uncompressed. That wouldn't work - as you discovered.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `.tobytes()` method to get what you want [(brief writeup here)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-tobytes-method/). Try this modification of your code snippet:

```
elif format == 'gif':
    corpo = PIL.Image.open(path)
    corpo_bytes = corpo.tobytes()
    answer =  corpo_bytes + ("\n").encode('UTF-8') #I need this line to end with a \n because it's the end of a HTTP answer
```

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it should be enough to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Now it doesn't give me the error of unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'GifImageFile' and 'bytes' and in fact it converts the gif into a large string of \x00\x00\x00\x00... but the client still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @xairopro What do you mean by "the client still doesn't recognize it"? What is the intended output?

Comment: I was saying that this is suposed to be part of a tcp multithreaded web server. And it is required that when the client does GET path HTTP/1.0 the server returns firstly a header and then this content.
The header is already created and works perfectly with other type of files(it is first a text string which is converted to binary before attaching it to the other files). The problem comes with this gif because I am not able to join my header in binary format with the gif. @HiddenMachine